# Generic Edit URL not working in Django

Tags: django, url, django-generic-views

I am using Django generic View but when i type

```
/book/edit/9/
```

Then it says no URL macthed in config file

My URL file is

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from myapp.views import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic import list_detail
from myapp.models import *
from django.views.generic import create_update
from django.views.generic.create_update import update_object


book_info = {'model' : Book}

(r'^book/create/$', create_update.create_object, book_info),
(r'^book/edit/(?P<object_id>d+)/$',create_update.update_object,book_info),
```

The create part is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the escape on the d (`\d`): you want `(r'^book/edit/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$',create_update.update_object,book_info)`

Comment: Thanks buddy , actually i copied from this link http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/appendixD/ , i thought they can't be wrong

Comment: Lol! It's in [the errata](http://www.djangobook.com/errata/), but I'm not sure who'd naturally read the errata page without being told to... there should really be a warning flag there.

Answer (score 0):

Correct on the backslash need. This bit me too. I suspect this is hurting a lot of newbies. This is a high priority for fixing.